# SQLite OnUpgrade data migration fail: execSQL probably not dropping tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite DB in my application and I'm trying to migrate it from version 4 to version 5. The aplication is working fine if I uninstall and then install again. I'll resume the problem for easy understanding.

In v4 I created this table:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Globals._TABLE +
        " ( " +
        Globals._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        Globals._PRIORITY + " INTEGER, " +
        Globals._FUNC_NAME + " TEXT " +
        ");";
```

In v5, I removed the columns _PRIORITY and _FUNC_NAME. I was also indexing with the index provided by my MySQL DB. I needed to create a way to index the DB internally. So I created the same table like this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Globals._TABLE +
                " ( " +
                Globals._SQLITE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                Globals._UPLOADED + " INTEGER, " +
                Globals._ID + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 " +
                ");";
```

My OnCreate method is this and is not throwing any errors:

```
@Override
public void onCreate( SQLiteDatabase db )
{
    try
    {
        db.execSQL( CREATE_TABLE );
    }
    catch( SQLException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }
}
```

I'm dropping the table with this query:

```
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Globals._TABLE;
```

My OnUpgrade method is this and is also not throwing errors:

```
SQLiteMigratorV5 migrator = new SQLiteMigratorV5( mContext, db );

    switch( newVersion )
    {
        case 5:
            migrator.saveData( );
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    try
    {
        db.execSQL( DROP_TABLE );
    }
    catch( SQLException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }

    onCreate( db );

    switch( newVersion )
    {
        case 5:
            migrator.restoreData( );
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Debugging the application I can see both onUpgrade and then OnCreate are being called. My class responsible for migration saves all the data, and was supposed to restore everything to the new tables. Debugging I can also say that all the rows from the old table are being correctly inserted in new table.

The problems reside when I try to access this data. I had other table that indexed elements from this first table by the id, I'm also recreating this other table and I need to index with the SQLite id. So I'm executing a rawQuery and retrieving a cursor:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Globals._TABLE + " WHERE " + Globals._ID + " = '1'";
Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery( query, null );
```

When I check the cursor columns I cannot find _SQLITE_ID neither _UPLOADED but I can find _PRIORITY and _FUNC_NAME, and that leads me to errors when I try to get the newly inserted row _SQLITE_ID to use in my other table.

```
for( cursor.moveToFirst( ); ! cursor.isAfterLast( ); cursor.moveToNext( ) )
{
    setSQLiteId( cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex( Globals._SQLITE_ID ) ) ); 
    ...
}
```

This piece of code leads me to this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

I checked everything more than once and I couldn't understand what is happening, my only assumption is that the old tables are not being dropped and the new ones are not being created because of the CREATE TABLE **IF NOT EXISTS**.

Anyone can give me a light on how to solve this problem?

**Ok, I solved the problem, but I still doesn't have an explanation**

My onUpgrade is called that way: storesData > drop tables > create tables > restores data.

In my store function I have this function:

```
public List< Client > getClientsWhereV4( String statement )
{
    if( statement == null )
    {
        statement = "";
    }

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Globals._TABLE + " " + statement;

    Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery( query, null );

    List< Client > clientList = new ArrayList<>( );
    for( cursor.moveToFirst( ); ! cursor.isAfterLast( ); cursor.moveToNext( ) )
    {
        Client client = new Client( mContext );

        // Already ignoring deleted columns
        client.setId( cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex( Globals._ID ) ) );

        clientList.add( client );
    }
    cursor.close( );

    return clientList;
}
```

And this is my restore function:

```
public List< Client > getClientsWhereV5( String statement )
{
    if( statement == null )
    {
        statement = "";
    }

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Globals._TABLE + " " + statement;

    Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery( query, null );

    List< Client > clientList = new ArrayList<>( );
    for( cursor.moveToFirst( ); ! cursor.isAfterLast( ); cursor.moveToNext( ) )
    {
        Client client = new Client();

        setSQLiteId( cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex( Globals.CLIENT_SQLITE_ID ) ) );
        if( cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex( Globals.CLIENT_UPLOADED ) ) == 1 )
        {
            setUploaded( true );
        }
        else
        {
            setUploaded( false );
        }
        setId( cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex( Globals.CLIENT_ID ) ) );

        clientList.add( client );
    }
    cursor.close( );

    return clientList;
}
```

If the store query is equal to the restore query, the error occurs, for example:

```
// v4    
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Globals._TABLE + " " + statement;
// v5
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Globals._TABLE + " " + statement;
```

If there is any difference, one has one more space or something like that, it works correctly. All the variables are local to the functions, I'm closing the cursors, and I just have no clue what is happening.

Comment: Try to exec `create table` without `if not exists` to check your hypothesis. if your table is not deleted, an error will occur.

Comment: Great comment! My hypothesis was wrong, no errors...and unfortunately it is still with the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is due to the cursor's position,

Try using `cursor.moveToFirst()` to first move your cursor to the first row of the data returned:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // Do your data access here, 
    // like cursor.getInt(...)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually this part of code is just hidden, I'll edit my post. Sorry about that.

Comment: I see. Not sure if this causes problem, your table_create sql, `Globals._FUNC_NAME + " TEXT, "` the comma should be removed? Same goes to your second table_create sql.

Comment: You're right, it would throw an error. But actually in my real code this is correct, the thing is I have more than 20 columns and i thought it would make it harder to understand the problem. Thank you again, and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score -1):

try some thing like . it should help

```
while(cursor.moveToNext){
//do something.
// access your data from table here.
}
```